# Calling TransparentBlt in MASM

Tags: windows, winapi, bitmap, transparency, masm

I'm trying to make a game in Masm (my teacher said so) and I'm experiencing some problems with the TransparentBlt() function.
I made a base for my game and I was using BitBlt, like this:

```
invoke SelectObject,memDC,hPerson ;// selecting the Handler of my bitmap
mov hFImage, eax ;// putting the result in hFImage(using in other locals)
invoke BitBlt,hDC,0,0,500,478,memDC,coordX,coordY,SRCCOPY ;// drawing
```

Where coordX and coordY represents the coordinates os the principal character and the default values(500, 478) are the size of my window.
It's was working really nice, but some day I was searching and I found the TransparentBlt, I was fascinated with it's demonstrating results. Then I tryied to put it on my project and just VUSH! What's going on? My character just disappeared...

```
invoke SelectObject,memDC,hPerson ;// same
mov hFImage, eax ;// same
RGB_b 0,160,192 ;// it puts the RGB of background on ebx
invoke TransparentBlt,hDC,0,0,500,478,memDC,coordX,coordY, 59, 30, ebx
```

In case you're wondering, 59 and 30 are the width and height of my bitmap.

Could some one tell me how to use TransparentBlt (more than just [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd145141(v=vs.85).aspx))? I'm really excited with this *almost PNG* function...

Comment: If you are looking for "PNG" like support - i.e. alpha channel support - why not use the `AlphaBlend` API that is also part of GDI. It produces a far better effect than TransparentBlt which (essentially) has to make a mask bitmap internally.

Comment: @ChrisBecke, I searched about this `AlphaBlend` at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183353(v=vs.85).aspx) and I realized that it's too complex for what I want to. I know it is probably better than `TransparentBlt`(efficiency, blablabla) but I just need something easy to see, understand and explain.

Comment: I don't see that it is at all complicated. The biggest problem is simply one of tooling: You need to give it a 4 channel bitmap and not a lot of paint tools support writing bmp's with ARGB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably passing the wrong dimensions.

Conceptually, `BitBlt` is a very simple function. You can think of it as simply "blitting" (copying) a block of pixels from one device context to another. So, it needs the following parameters:

1. The source device context
2. The destination device context
3. The origin (upper-left corner) of the source rectangle.
4. The origin (upper-left corner) of the destination rectangle.
5. The dimensions (width and height).

It also takes a raster-operation code, but you're passing `SRCCOPY`, which means exactly what I described above: copy a block of pixels from one device context to another. You can do fancier stuff with `BitBlt`, but we'll ignore that.

The thing to notice here is that `BitBlt` never does any resizing. The source and destination rectangles can have different *origins* (*i.e.*, they can start at different coordinates), they they always have the same *sizes* (*i.e.*, the source and destination always have the same width and height).

If you want to do *resizing* (stretching or compressing) of the bitmap when you blit it, there is a function that can do that: `StretchBlt`. `StretchBlt` is basically just a version of `BitBlt` that is capable of stretching. It can scale the source image up or down in size, so it takes *separate* dimensions for the source and the destination.

What does this have to do with `TransparentBlt`? Well, `TransparentBlt` *also* supports resizing. It is basically an extended version of `StretchBlt` that supports a limited form of transparency.<sup>*</sup>

So the progression is basically this:

- `BitBlt` is the basic function.
- `StretchBlt` builds on this by adding the ability to *resize* the source image as it is drawn onto the destination.
- `TransparentBlt` builds on this by adding the ability to make a particular color in the source image transparent as it is drawn onto the destination.

I think this conceptual understanding is important, because it helps you keep straight how the functions should be used.

It also helps answer your question. If you want to use `TransparentBlt` as a transparent equivalent to `BitBlt`, then you don't want any stretching, and you therefore need to pass exactly the same dimensions for the source as for the destination.

In other words, call `TransparentBlt` as follows:

```
invoke TransparentBlt, hDC, 0, 0, 500, 478, memDC, coordX, coordY, 500, 478, ebx
```

One final note: you really need to be checking the return values of Windows API functions, otherwise you won't know whether they are failing. Generally, they will return `FALSE` (== 0) on failure. *Sometimes* (check the MSDN documentation to see if this is true), the `GetLastError` function can be called immediately after another function has returned `FALSE` to get additional information about *why* the function failed. Your code doesn't check *any* of the return values, so you have no idea if the functions failed or not, and therefore no good way of knowing where to start debugging.

__
<sub><sup>*</sup> Technically, everything that you can do with `TransparentBlt` can be done with `StretchBlt` using that last parameter, the raster-operation code. And, in fact, this is how it had to be done prior to Windows 98/2000, before the `TransparentBlt` function existed. And even on Windows 98, you often wanted to do it the old-fashioned way, avoiding `TransparentBlt`, because `TransparentBlt` had a leak in it. Now that those days are well behind us, everyone just uses `TransparentBlt` because it is much simpler.</sub>

Comment: Thanks about the large explanation! Using the 'Debug' way I was able to see what was wrong.